# Firebase Failed to generate a private key. Please try again in a few minutes error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, private-key

I'm trying to generate a new key on firebase, but I got the error

```
Failed to generate a private key. Please try again in a few minutes.
```

by looking at the HTTP responses it gets a 400

[image]

so, I tried to give the right roles to the firebase service account it tells on the image above. Here is the final setting on IAM (further useless roles have been added for testing purposes, like the owner one):

[image]

after that, I got the same error. Any hint?

Comment: The error says `Key creation is not allowed on this service account.` There is an org policy to prevent key creation [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-service-accounts) Edit your post and provide more details: a) is your project part of an organization; b) is the constraint `Disable service account key creation` enabled.

Comment: that was the problem: the organization's constraint `Disable service account key creation` was enabled by default. could you move this comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says `Key creation is not allowed on this service account`.

There is an org policy to prevent key creation:

[Restricting service account usage](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/restricting-service-accounts)

You can disable the constraint via the web GUI or the CLI:

```
gcloud resource-manager org-policies disable-enforce \
  iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation \
  --organization=<ORG_ID>
```